# Devel::Cover with options for test coverage

Tags: perl, testing, code-coverage

In a project I am working on the directory layout that does not have a lib directory so we have

```
/X.pm
/X/Y.pm
...
/t/test.t
```

when I run

```
$ PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover make test
$ cover
```

I get report only for the files in t/

how can I tell Devel::Cover to report about all the files in the current directory except those in t?

I thought I can do it by this:

```
cover -t +inc . -inc t
```

but I get:

```
Unknown option: inc
Invalid command line options at /home/gabor/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Devel/Cover/Report/Html_minimal.pm line 677.
```

from [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cover/lib/Devel/Cover.pm) it is unclear to me how can I supply these options.

Comment: I think you're supposed to give the arguments in the `-MDevel::Cover` line as in `-MDevel::Cover=-dir,.`. Furthermore, I really don't think the `inc` arguments do what you want: they specify files to *ignore* such as modules in `@INC`. I haven't tested this though, I don't have D::C on this machine.

Comment: Question was crossposted to http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.qa/2011/01/msg12662.html and already answered there.

Answer (score 1):

`cover` doesn't actually generate coverage statistics, only reports on it IIRC.

Also, the `+inc` seems to need to be a part of PERL5OPT (comma separated to have -M pass them to `import()`, e.g. `-MDevel::Cover=+inc,"/sometething"`)

I could be wrong - I only ever use Devel::Cover when actually running .t files, so never tried to do "all modules in directory" approach.